# Any striking difference between class/instance methods vs static methods for use in applications?

Tags: javascript, api, express, static-methods, class-method

I am building APIs for an application. I want to know if there is any difference between writing the functionality methods as this:

```
class Foo {
  static method1(req, res) {}
  static method2(req, res) {}
}
```

and

```
class Foo {
  method1(req, res) {}
  method2(req, res) {}
}
```

I know static methods are made directly on the class and are not callable on instances of the class and they are often used to create utility functions but I just want to know if there is a disadvantage or any effect if static is not added while creating the functionalities for the application.

Comment: This question is too vague. You already pointed out the difference between static and instance methods; whether there is an advantage to making a method static depends on how you want your API to be used. If you don't think developers should have to instantiate an object in order to use a specific method, then make it static.

Comment: @333 I got you. I thought it's a must to add the 'static' keyword to functionality methods. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `static` is not added, then the method can only be called on an instance of the object.

If `static` is added, then the method can only be called with the class name prefix, not an instance of the object.

If you have a method that could be static (does not reference any instance data or use `this` to refer to an object instance), then you can make it either static or not static.  If you make it non-static, it will still work just fine, but it will only be callable on an instance of the object itself or with a direct reference to `Foo.prototype.method()`.

So, the disadvantage of not making a static method actually be declared static is that it's not as clean to use it when you don't have an instance of the object around.  That's what static methods were invented for - to make it clean to declare and use functions namespaced to your class that don't require an instance.

Comment: you killed it absolutely and completely. Thanks a lot!